# Unexplained segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c

I'm currently learning c programming. I've written this code as part of an assignment and keep getting Segmentation faults.
Prototypes:

```
#define ALLOC_ERROR -1

typedef struct monom
{
  int coefficient;    
  int power;        
} Monom;

int insertNewMonom(Monom** polynom, int base, int power, unsigned int size);
bool findPlace(Monom** polynom, int power, unsigned int size, int* place);
void printPolyMul(Monom* polynom1, unsigned int polynom1Size, Monom* polynom2, unsigned int polynom2Size);
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
void printPolyMul(Monom* polynom1, unsigned int polynom1Size, Monom* polynom2, unsigned int polynom2Size)
{
    Monom *mulPolynom = NULL, *temp = NULL;
    unsigned int  count = 0;
    int i, j, size=0, base, power;

    for(i=0; i<polynom1Size; i++){
      for(j=0; j<polynom2Size; j++){ 
        if(count==size){
            size = (size*2)+1;
            temp = realloc (sumPolynom, size * sizeof *sumPolynom);
            if(!temp){
                fprintf(stderr, "Allocation error\n");
                exit(ALLOC_ERROR);
            }
            else
                sumPolynom = temp;
        }                       
        base = (polynom1[i].coefficient)*(polynom2[j].coefficient);
        power = (polynom1[i].power)+(polynom2[j].power);
        count += insertNewMonom(&mulPolynom, base, power, count);
    }
}

temp =  realloc (mulPolynom, count * sizeof *mulPolynom);
if(!temp){
    fprintf(stderr, "Allocation Error\n");
    exit(ALLOC_ERROR);
}
else 
    mulPolynom = temp;

printPolynom(mulPolynom, count);            
free(mulPolynom);
}
int insertNewMonom(Monom** polynom, int base, int power, unsigned int size)
{
    int i, place;
    bool new_flag;
    Monom tempMonom;

    tempMonom.coefficient = base;
    tempMonom.power = power;    

    if(!base)
        return 0;
    new_flag = findPlace(polynom, power, size, &place);
    if(new_flag){
        if(place==size){
            (*polynom)[place] = tempMonom;
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            for(i=size; i>place; i--)
                (*polynom)[i] = (*polynom)[i-1];
            (*polynom)[place] = tempMonom;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else{
        polynom[place]->coefficient += base;
        return 0;
    }   
}

bool findPlace(Monom** polynom, int power, unsigned int size, int* place)
{
    int curr;   
    for(curr=0; curr<size; curr++){
        if(polynom[curr]->power==power){
            *place = curr;
            return false;
        } 
        if(polynom[curr]->power<power){
            if(curr)        
                *place = curr-1;
            else
                *place = curr;
            return true;
        }
    }
    *place = size; 
    return true;
}
```

I managed to track down the exact point where the code crashes. It's when `bool findPlace(Monom** polynom, int power, unsigned int size, int* place)` is called for the third time, on the second for iteration (`curr=1`) when `polynom[curr]->power` is being checked.
I'll mention that `insertNewPolynom()` was used earlier tin the program for receiving `polynom1` and `polynom2` and worked just fine.

Comment: Don't need to cast malloc in C http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: You can write: 'mulPolynom = realloc(mulPolynom, size * sizeof *mulPolynom)'

Comment: @ViktorSimkó this leaks in case of error.

Comment: @Quentin Then its better to write `mulPolynom = realloc(mulPolynom, size * sizeof(Monom))` ?

Comment: @ViktorSimkó Thankes for the reply, i think i'ii keep casting until i'll have a better understanding of when its safe not to. any idea about why i get segmentation fault?

Comment: @AGal *not* casting is **always** safe. It's what the type system is for. You should wonder when casting *is* safe.

Comment: @ViktorSimkó no, you should store `realloc`'s return value in another variable, check if it succeeded, *then* overwrite`mulPolynom`.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, understood it now. Just haven't known what did You mean.

Comment: @Quentin so `temp = realloc(mulPolynom, size * sizeof *mulPolynom);
mulPolynom = temp;`
is better?

Comment: @AGal with an `if(!temp) { /* error, bailout */ }` in-between, yep

Comment: @Quentin still getting that segmentation fault. any other ideas?

Comment: BTW, the cast/ no cast issue and testing `realloc()` are not key to the problem.  Fixing them will not solve the issue.  OTOH, these 2 side issues, like spelling/grammar errors in a report, create distractions.  So when code is not behaving as expected, it _is_ useful to attend to them so all may focus on the real issue.

Comment: 1) post `Monom` definition, 2) post `printPolynom(mulPolynom, count);` 3) are all warnings enabled?  4) Are functions prototyped somewhere before 1st use? They are not properly prototyped in the posted code.

Comment: @chux 1) posted, 2) its irellevant because the program doesn't get to that part, 3) yes, 4) posted the protorypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size allocated is too small.

Consider `size = polynom1Size*polynom2Size; realloc (mulPolynom, size * sizeof *mulPolynom); ... if(place==size){ (*polynom)[place] = tempMonom;`.

Code is attempting to modify element  `[size]` yet only has space for elements `0,1,2, ... size-1`.

Without digging deep, it appears `realloc (mulPolynom, (size + 1) * sizeof *mulPolynom);` is needed.

Comment: I checked that aspect, the logical size is always smaller than the pysical size...

Comment: Suggest writing a function to use inside each `[foo(x, size)]` array access that test if `0<=x && x < size`.  Code likely fails for 1) too small memory (this answer) 2) Array access out of bounds. (this comment).  BTW: Did you try `realloc (mulPolynom, (size + 1) * sizeof *mulPolynom)`?

Comment: To be clear, this answer is not about a _logical size_ vs. a _physical size_ (bytes).  It is about typical polynomial representation that is usually index `0,1,2,3, N` and so needs `N+1` elements.

Comment: That what i meant, the size is always at least N+1

Answer (score 0):

In insertNewMonom you have statements

```
 (*polynom)[place] = tempMonom;
```

But `tempMonom` is a local variable and ceases to exist when the function returns. Any reference to it later on will either produce garbage or crash.

Comment: but when i write (*polynom)[place] = tempMonom i'm actually copying it, so later i wont have to reference to it, no?